# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, in Internet explorer - Parse JS SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using Parse javascript SDK with Cocos2dx for a web application. My application is running well on Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera but on Internet Explorer. I am getting

> CRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.

or sometimes

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x4c7, The operation was canceled by the user.

issue on IE browser console when any parse cloud function gets called.

I am getting

> errorCode = 100 and message = XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"

error in parse cloud error block.

Apart from this when I am trying to hit parse url with mount point "https://example.com:1337/parse"

It response with {"error":"unauthorized"} in chrome, firefox, safari, opera thats fine, but in Internet Explorer this url not working it Showing "HTTP 403 Forbidden This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage."

Please help me where is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello @md-zakir,

Can you show me your request header ?

Comment: Hi Julien, I am using IE 11, its not showing the request header when error occures.

Comment: you don't have debugging tools to show more information ? @md-zakir

Comment: @MDZakir which version of IE are you using? also, like what the previous commentor said, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Verify you're initializing Parse-Server properly. Your app is making the requests, but is not passing authorization credentials. If you are using the JS SDK, you need to make sure the appId and JS API key (if you set one on your server) are correct before passing them into the Parse-Server initializer. If you are using the REST API, it sounds like you aren't passing the authorization credentials into the header.